# Check if all lotto numbers are covered in input

Tags: java, programming-challenge

Each ticket for the Pick-10 lotto has 10 unique numbers ranging from 1 to 99. Suppose you buy a lot of tickets and like to have them cover all numbers from 1 to 99. Write a program that reads the ticket numbers from a file and checks whether all numbers are covered. Assume the last number in the file is 0. Suppose the file contains the numbers:

> ```
> 80 3 87 62 30 90 10 21 46 27
> 12 40 83 9 39 88 95 59 20 37
> 80 40 87 67 31 90 11 24 56 77
> 11 48 51 42 8 74 1 41 36 53
> 52 82 16 72 19 70 44 56 29 33
> 54 64 99 14 23 22 94 79 55 2
> 60 86 34 4 31 63 84 89 7 78
> 43 93 97 45 25 38 28 26 85 49
> 47 65 57 67 73 69 32 71 24 66
> 92 98 96 77 6 75 17 61 58 13
> 35 81 18 15 5 68 91 50 76
> 0
> ```

Your program should display:

"The tickets cover all numbers"

Suppose the file contains the numbers

> ```
> 11 48 51 42 8 74 1 41 36 53
> 52 82 16 72 19 70 44 56 29 33
> 0
> ```

Your program should display:

> "The tickets do not cover all numbers"

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LottoCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Create an array of booleans
        boolean[] neededNumbers = new boolean[99];

        //Prompt input
        System.out.println("Enter your ticket numbers: ");
        int ticketNumber = input.nextInt();

        while (ticketNumber != 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= neededNumbers.length; i++) {
                neededNumbers[i] = true;
            }
            ticketNumber = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < neededNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (neededNumbers[i] == false) {
                System.out.println("You do not have all the numbers.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You have all the numbers.");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

First, this will not work with the input `99`.  Arrays are 0-indexed, but when you create one, you need to specify the value you wish `.length` to have, which is `100`.

This part is also erroneous:

```
while (ticketNumber != 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= neededNumbers.length; i++) {
        neededNumbers[i] = true;
    }
    ticketNumber = input.nextInt();
}
```

Here, you input the values until the input equals `0`, but you loop from `1` through `needeNumbers.length` and set the values to `true`.  First off, this will crash when you run it because the value `neededNumbers[neededNumbers.length]` does not exist.  Additionally, your logic is wrong as you do not want all the values of `neededNumbers` to be set to  `true`, just the input ones:

```
while (ticketNumber != 0) {
    neededNumbers[ticketNumber] = true;
    ticketNumber = input.nextInt();
}
```

This loop is almost right, but you check the value an index `0`, which you did not set to `true` because `0` was the value to exit the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < neededNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (neededNumbers[i] == false) {
        System.out.println("You do not have all the numbers.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You can solve this problem in one of two ways - starting with `i = 1`, or changing your `while` loop to use `neededNumbers[ticketNumber - 1] = true;` and intializing it to `new boolean[99]`, like you currently do.  This will have value `1` be stored in the `0` index of the array, so all values will be set to `true` once all the numbers in the range of 1 - 99 have been entered.

Comment: Yeah, I about the logic after the first for-loop, I actually knew that but copied the wrong code... And I thought I fixed the last loop but I guess I forgot... Thank you soooo much for your help! I will remember and practice what you taught me.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution has many faults. One thing that clearly stands out is the fact that the Boolean array is 1 element too small, as 99 is not a valid index in an array of size 99 (which has indices 0...98).

Another thing is that for every number in the input, you transverse all 99 entries of your array. This part is unnecessary and makes your program very slow. You know that the index of `ticketNumber` is the value, so a search is useless. Just set `neededNumbers[ticketNumber] = true;` and that's it. This should speed up your code around 50x on average. For such a small problem it may not matter, but if you want to do the problem with a million entries, it is the only way to solve it.

Comment: Ah my bad I was using an online ide at a public computer that didn't work with more than a couple of inputs at once. Thank you so much, I will remember the solution that you gave me.

Answer (score 3):

If you re-word your question, all you are supposed to find is if a collection of numbers, where each value is in the interval `[1, X]`, run from `1` to `X`. If this collection of numbers do not contain duplicates, you just need to make sure that a `List` representation of this collection has a `size()` of `X`.

A more efficient way is to declare a [`new BitSet(X)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), iterate through your collection of numbers by setting the appropriate `index - 1` to `true`, and finally checking that the result of calling [`cardinality()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality--) returns `X`.

Comment: agh my bad. What'd a better name for this type of problem just so I could have a idea of how to word questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop could be simplified:

```
while (ticketNumber != 0) {
    neededNumbers[ticketNumber - 1] = true;
    ticketNumber = input.nextInt();
}
```

Arrays allow random access, so if you can map your input (a one-based ticketNumber integer) to your array indexing (zero-based), you can avoid looping through the array.  I suspect you had linked-lists on your mind when developing your algorithm.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think of that... haha thanks